# How to put elements next to each other horizontally?

Tags: c#, html, css, css-float

I've got seven Panels (that each one of them holding another 5 Panels) that together makes a some sort of dynamic table based on my C# code. How I make my Panels stand horizontally next to each other?

I have tried `float:left;`, but it didn't work.

The Panels are this:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel0"  CssClass = "evenCulomn" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass = "oddCulomn" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass = "evenCulomn"  runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3"  CssClass = "evenCulomn" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel4"  CssClass = "oddCulomn" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel5" CssClass = "evenCulomn"  runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel6" CssClass = "oddCulomn"  runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Firstly, remove the `<br />` tags.  Then, wrap all of these pseudo-elements with another `<div style="overflow:hidden;">` and then set each column (note the spelling of column) to float:left within it.

Comment: thanks, i didn't even see those <br/> ! that worked as a charme!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

float:left will work as long as the panels will fit into the container. Once the width of the container is filled they will wrap.

I think your problem is that your panels need to have a fixed  width - otherwise they are 100% wide and will take up all the space and the float:left is effectively ignored.

Something like this:

```
.evenCulomn .oddCulom
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: apparently it worked without the width, but i think that if i'll try that on different browsers i might have a problem. so i'll fix the width anyway. thanx!

Answer (score 1):

```
.evenCulomn
{
 float:left
}
.oddCulomn
{
 float:left;
}
```